# efficient/clever way to compute a physics formula in python

Tags: python, scientific-computing

I'm looking for an efficient way to compute the result of a (complex) mathematical function.

right now it looks comparable to:

```
def f(x):
    return x**2
def g(x):
    if not x: return 1
    return f(x)*5
def h(x):
    return g(x)

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    print(list(executor.map(h, params)))
```

since every function call is costly in Python, the code should already run faster if f(x) is merged with g(x). Unfortunately in that case the 'return ...' line of the g(x) function becomes very long already. Furthermore there are currently actually 6 functions defined in total, so the complete formula occupies several lines.

So, what's a clever way to compute the result of a physics formula?

**EDIT:**

Thank you so far, but my question is not really about this specific snippet of code but more about the way to implement physics formulas in Python. For example one could also define the expression as a string and evaluate it using eval() but that is obviously slower.

To be more specific I have a potential and want to implement it parallel. Therefore I call my version of "h(x)" using the map function of a ProcessPoolExecutor (with different values each time). But is it best practice to define the function as a function that calls other functions or uses variables? Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: You'd better have a look into [numpy](https://numpy.org/) if you want to play with large arrays.

Comment: this is a good tip. What is the best way to submit a np.array to a PoolExcecutor?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the line is in danger of being problematically long, but if you're concerned about the length of the `return ...` line you could use intermediate values, e.g.:

```
def g(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    x2 = x ** 2
    return x2 * 5
```

As an aside, in this context it is incorrect to use the `is` operator as in `x is 0`. It does not check for numerical equality, which is what `==` does. The `is` operator checks that the two operands refer to exactly the same object in memory, which happens to have the same behaviour as `==` in this case because the Python interpreter is intelligently reusing number objects. It can lead to confusing errors, for example:

```
a = 1234
b = 1233
a == (b + 1) # True
a is (b + 1) # False
```

In practice, `is` is mainly used only to check if a value `is None`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def formula(x):
    if not x :
        return 1
    return x*x*5
```